# coreference resolution horribly long with corenlp

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I have a problem , I want to resolve the coreference problem of a document and I am trying to run the example provided by the following [link](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html)

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.data.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.data.Mention;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

import java.util.Properties;

public class CorefExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Annotation document = new Annotation("Barack Obama was born in Hawaii.  He is the president.  Obama was elected in 2008.");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,coref");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    System.out.println("---");
    System.out.println("coref chains");
    for (CorefChain cc : document.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation.class).values()) {
      System.out.println("\t"+cc);
    }
    for (CoreMap sentence : document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      System.out.println("---");
      System.out.println("mentions");
      for (Mention m : sentence.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefMentionsAnnotation.class)) {
        System.out.println("\t"+m);
       }
    }
  }
}
```

There is just one single sentence to solve and this is about one hour that my program is running. Is it normal?
It tooks me about one hour to have the result

I ve run the program with this option :-Xmx4g

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use 6GB of RAM? In the [documentation](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html) they mention that the new version of CoreNLP is using neural networks for coreference resolution, so it will be slower than the rule-based algorithm and it needs more RAM. In my case it was slow and run out of memory for two sentences and 4 GB RAM.

The example command for the neural system in English uses 5GB for the 3.7.0 CoreNLP version:

```
java -Xmx5g -cp stanford-corenlp-3.7.0.jar:stanford-corenlp-models-3.7.0.jar:* edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,coref -coref.algorithm neural -file example_file.txt
```

You might also try to specify which algorithm you prefer with the parameter:

```
coref.algorithm
```

For instance,

```
PropertiesUtils.asProperties("annotators", "your annotators","coref.algorithm","neural");
```

There are three available approaches to choose from.

In the [basic](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html) example code, they use "**dcoref**", instead of "**coref**" as a coreference resolution annotator and this is the deterministic approach, which is faster and less accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have this particular problem, but also ran out of heap space using CoreNLP and coref as an annotator property. The problem was that I was creating `new StanfordCoreNLP(props)` multiple times, instead of using the same object.